# Insert into a table with select from two tables

Tags: oracle

Under Oracle 19c I want to insert into a table with select from two tables.

I tried this but get ann error message right parenthesis missing.

```
INSERT INTO GL_TD_RESSEA (RESS_SEAID, RESS_CREAPAR, RESS_IDIND)
select (select ID,
               RESAD_CREAPAR
        from   GL_TD_DECOUVERTE_RESA 
        where  UPPER(resad_PNOM) = UPPER(:P24_PRENOM_DU_DEMANDEUR)
        AND    UPPER(RESAD_NOM) = UPPER(:P24_NOM_DU_DEMANDEUR), 
               ID
        from   GL_INDIVIDU
        where  UPPER(IND_PNOM) = UPPER(:P24_PRENOM_DU_DEMANDEUR)
        AND    UPPER(IND_NOM) = UPPER(:P24_NOM_DU_DEMANDEUR)
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to enclose`SELECT` query with parenthesis and also two columns from one query and one column from another query is also not valid statement.

It should be:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(...)
SELECT ... FROM... ; -- only one SELECT query -- can use multiple tables
```

Just remove paranthesis and use `JOIN` as follows:

```
INSERT INTO GL_TD_RESSEA (RESS_SEAID, RESS_CREAPAR, RESS_IDIND) 
select T1.ID, 
       T1.RESAD_CREAPAR,
       T2.ID
  from GL_TD_DECOUVERTE_RESA T1
  JOIN GL_INDIVIDU T2 ON UPPER(T1.resad_PNOM) = UPPER(T2.IND_PNOM) 
   AND UPPER(T1.RESAD_NOM) = UPPER(T2.IND_NOM)
 where UPPER(T1.resad_PNOM) = UPPER(:P24_PRENOM_DU_DEMANDEUR) 
   AND UPPER(T1.RESAD_NOM) = UPPER(:P24_NOM_DU_DEMANDEUR);
```